# How do you get code like this to run in JsFiddle.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I'm looking at sample code on how to draw shapes using only JavaScript.
I'm trying to test this sample code in JSFiddle.net, and while hitting 'Run' doesn't produce any errors, the result is completely blank.

Does anyone know how to make something actually appear on the screen in JsFiddle.net?

```
draw = function() {
    //sky
    background(172, 238, 247);
    //ground
    fill(95, 156, 83);
    rect(0, 350, 400, 50);
};
draw();
```

Link to non-working Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/skdopL1b/

Comment: because you have no markup :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way javascript works with HTML to draw things is through the Canvas API. First you have to contextualization and establish interactions between JS code and `<canvas>` element. This is done with built in function and then a little bit of code to make it short-hand.

```
<html>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
const c = document.getElementById("canvas"); //Grab canvas element to use as object
const ctx = c.getContext('2d'); //Function that enable the 2d functions of Canvas API
ctx.fillRect(0,0,10,10) //Example of ctx function
<script>
</html>
```

From the JS Fiddle you gave us, It looks like you probably copied functions from a video that pre-established these function as they are not normal canvas function but custom functions. I can show you example of how to write one of these custom functions

```
function background(red,green,blue) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb('+red+','+green+','+blue+')';;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height); //Makes a rectangle the size of the canvas
}
background(172,238,247); //Creates a canvas sized rectangle with rgb(172,238,247)
```

You will have to either find his function declarations or write your own (or just use the raw canvas functions) to work with the javascript this way. You also need to define a canvas element with an ID. Lucky for you Im working on making a JSFiddle that works for you since you seem fairly new to this whole HTML5/JS thing.

-------EDIT-------

Heres your fiddle link friend, I included comments to help you understand everything https://jsfiddle.net/xwqg1cez/2/